# Unknown column in 'field list' error on MySQL Update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

i echoed the query below: (query is safe)

```
UPDATE otelozellik 
   SET isim_tr='test', 
       aciklama_tr='<p>test1</p>', 
       uyari_tr='test', 
       tag_tr='test' 
 WHERE id='1'
```

> Database Error: Unknown column
>   'aciklama_tr' in 'field list'

I changed the order of columns, the one after `isim_tr` keeps giving error. When I move `isim_tr` to the last then the one after `id` giving the same error. But moving them to the last position is not a solution for me because table will be dynamic to add new columns when necessary. need an absolute solution.

UPDATE: LATEST SCREENSHOT: http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/7215/mysqlerror.jpg

Solved. Solution is answered below. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is the table structure right now?

Comment: That is strange. Everything appears right.

Comment: the only thing strange is the where clause WHERE id='1'. I would have written it as WHERE id=1 but i have no idea it this means anything.

Comment: You could try `REPLACE INTO` instead. Might help if the error results from a mismatching WHERE clause and id=11.

Comment: Seems correct. Check your table name, just in case.

Comment: to clarify, the field that is unrecognized is whatever field is listed second no matter what field it is?

Comment: A quick google search gave me a few similar bugreports http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1689 - restarting mysqld helped once, yet most of them seem to be update and user errors still.

Comment: screenshot updated. tried restarting sql didnt work for me.

Comment: @dqhendricks not exactly, if isim_tr is in 2nd position, 3rd giving error. When i tried isim_tr at last position then 2nd giving error.

Comment: @Mustafa: If you posted a correct answer for this issue then please communicate this by marking your answer as correct. That way people who see this question because it's relevant to their situation will see a correct answer on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. Thank you a lot everyone for their help.

Right Query for solution is:

```
UPDATE `holidaycholic`.`otelbilgi` SET `otelbilgi`.`isim_tr`='test2', `otelbilgi`.`aciklama_tr`='<p>test2</p>', `otelbilgi`.`uyari_tr`='test2', `otelbilgi`.`tag_tr`='test2' WHERE `otelbilgi`.`id`=1
```

No idea why but that worked for me.

Comment: You're explicitly specifying the schema - It seems like your table definition might be a little screwy...

Comment: because you removed `quotes` in the where clause id.

Answer (score 0):

'field list' errors are caused when you try to load data into a field that doesn't exist. Double check that you spelled your field names correctly.

Your post says that you need to add "dynamic columns". A properly structured database shouldn't have a need for that sort of thing. However, if you do want to add columns from php, you need to add them to the table before you try to insert data in those fields. You can use the ALTER TABLE statement to do this:
`ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype`

Comment: did you not look at his posted imaged??

Comment: I think he means dynamic columns as in "dynamically building the query to only set certain columns"

Comment: @dqhendricks dunno how I missed the screenshot. Guess I'm stumped.

Comment: Dynamic columns is not an important thing. i will add new columns when i want to add more languages. also queries are built automatically depending on fields. latest screenshot here: http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/7215/mysqlerror.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just to double-check are all the characters you're using the standard ASCII characters or are you using an unusual character set?

Try inserting data into the table using phpMyAdmin or similar - If it works, copy the code it generates and run it yourself using the mysql client.

Assuming that still works, compare the generated code with the SQL generated by your PHP

Comment: My character set is "utf8_general_ci" and adding new items both work thru my script or thru phpmyadmin. I just cant update them thru my script, i will try to update thru phpmyadmin now.

Comment: I could see the screenshot was phpMyAdmin but it he didn't specify if it worked, You're right that it was an update not an insert though - I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax which works for me all time:

```
 "INSERT INTO table(`code`, `description`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($code)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($description)."')";
```

"table" is a table with an AUTO_INCREMENT index.